# embed local image using html works in outlook2010 but stop working in outlook2013

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I've created an outlook add-in for outlook 2010, it's used for apply email templates quickly.
In this add-in I'm using HTML as the templates.  There're many images referenced to local resources.
Codes like that:

```
mailItem.HTMLBody="... <image src=\"c:\\path\\to\\image.gif\" />...";
```

It works perfectly with outlook2010, but the images are not displayed when use this add-in with outlook 2013

Anyone with any ideas, it would be approciated.

Answer (score 0):

Never created an add-in before but normally if you are escaping quotations and are specifying a link you normally have to double them up as it will be escaping the P T & I

```
<img src=\"c:\\path\\to\\images.gif\" />
```

I could be wrong though.

Comment: thank you for answering! but that's not the problem, it's typo, my bad

Answer (score 0):

Why not add the images as attachments, set the PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID property on the image attachments, then refer to them through cid (src="cid:xyz") in your HTML?